# HTML formatting so that my form doesn't look bad

Tags: html, css, forms

I'm trying to make an HTML form that looks good.  But my formatting is a little off.  I am also trying to make the form responsive.  I need the first name and last name on one line. The address on the next.  The city and state on the third and the email and phone number on the fourth and the submit button and privacy link on the last.  I have tried using another table within a table and that wasn't very good.

My questions is how to I fix the fields to line up together. Right now the address bar is shorter than the others.  All the lines are different lengths and I want to make them the same length and have them line up correctly.
[Here is my sample](https://jsfiddle.net/4whbhk3b/)

```css
:before, :after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p, li {
  letter-spacing:-0.05vw;
}
h1 {
 letter-spacing:-0.3vw;
}

#p3 {
  background-color:white;
}

table {
  border:0;
  padding:0;
  border-collapse:collapse;
 }

div {
 
  float:left;
}

.btn {
 font-family:Oswald-RegularItalic;
  font-size:1.2vw;
  width:25%;
  display:block;
 float:left;
 margin-left:2%;
 background-color:#00A151;
 height:2.5vw;
 border: 0 none;
 color:white;
 margin-bottom:10%;
 
} 

#p3 h3 {
  color:#00A151;
  font-size:2vw;
  font-family:Oswald-RegularItalic;
  margin:10% 0 5% 0;
  padding:0;
}

#p3 div {
 margin:0;
}
#fname, #lname, #address, #city, #state , #zip, #phone{
  height:35px;
 line-height:35px;
 font-size:20px;
 border: 1px solid #1B75B7;
}

#fname, #lname, #address, #city, #state {
  margin-bottom:3px;
}
#fname {
 margin-right:4px;}

#fname, #lname{
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 white-space:nowrap;
 width:48%;
}

#address {
  width:97%;
}

#city {
  width:86%;
}
#state {
  width:10%;
}
#zip, #phone {
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
#zip {
  width:40%;
}
#phone {
  width:56%;
}

#p3 input::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:25px;
}
#p3 input:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
    font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:25px;
}
#p3 input::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:25px;
}
#p3 input:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
    font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:25px;
}
#p3 #state::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit browsers */
    font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:0;
}
#p3  #state:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:0;
}
#p3  #state::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:0;
}
#p3  #state:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10+ */
   font-size:1.2vw;
 color:#1B75B7;
 font-family:Oswald-BoldItalic;
 padding-left:0;
}
#p3 .submitBtn {
 margin:0 10% 10% 0;
}

p3 p {
  font-size:14px;
}
#p3 .privacy {
  font-size:1vw;
  font-family:Oswald-RegularItalic;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" id="p3" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
   <td width="100%" colspan="3" align="center"><h3>Where would you like us to send your brochure and DVD?</h3>
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td width="25%"></td>
   <td width="50%">
     <form class="contactForm" method="post" action="send.php">
          <div>
            <input name="fname" type="text"  placeholder="First Name"id="fname" required>
   <input name="lname" type="text"  placeholder="Last Name"id="lname" required><br>
   <input name="address" type="text"  placeholder="Address"id="address" required>
   <input name="city" type="text"  placeholder="City" id="city" required>
   <input name="state" type="text"  placeholder="State" id="state" maxlength="2" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^A-z]/, '')"  required>
   <input name="zip" type="text"  placeholder="Zip Code" id="zip" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" maxlength="2" required>
   <input name="phone" type="tel"  placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required>
   <input class="btn submitBtn" id="send" value="Send It!" type="submit">
   <p class="privacy">Privacy Policy</p>
          </div>
  </form>
   </td>
   <td width="25%"></td>
 </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
```

Comment: You may want to answer these questions within your question to clarify your question: What's the problem? What have you tried to fix it so far? What research have you done? What was the problem with the research you found? You can also read the [how to ask guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can you change the html ?

Comment: Your line with address input has less width than other lines, because other lines contain two inputs each with 1px border, resulting in extra 2px. You can force your inputs to include border in calculated width with `box-sizing: border-box;` css property.

[__JSFiddle__](https://jsfiddle.net/4whbhk3b/1/)

Comment: I have created a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/v1btL602/1/ is this what you want?

Comment: If you need percentage for width and need to be precise, I would recommend using box-sizing: border-box:

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/4whbhk3b/3/

Comment: Michael Eugene, That absolutely worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using tables to format, this rule is ironclad, tables are ONLY for tabular data.

Furthermore this is non-responsive, it will look terrible on mobile devices (resize and see for yourself).

I recommend you use a framework to make your life easier. [Bourbon / neat](http://bourbon.io/) if you're familiar with sass or perhaps [pure css](http://purecss.io/forms/) if you aren't.

Tip: Don't hesitate to put inputs on new lines, scrolling down is less of a problem then you might think, make full use of your horizontal screen real-estate.